# Partner Community License Connected OAuth App

Tags: connected-apps, licenses

Can a partner community license be used to connect to an OAuth Connected App in Salesforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the partner community user license can be used to connect to OAuth Connected App.

Except username/password oauth flow you should be able to use the connected app to connect to salesforce and use it for authorization(user agent/ web server or JWT is supported for community license types).

If you want them to authorize, the authorization url for communities would look like below

https://{full community path}/services/oauth2/authorize?​response_type=token&client_id=your_app_id&redirect_uri=your_redirect_uri

full community path - This is the community domain with the path prefix .

Comment: Thanks! Two questions: when you say "Except username/password oauth flow you should be able..." are you saying that you cannot use the username/password flow? 

And my second question: in the URL, you have "https:///services/oauth2..." Should the first part of that URL be login.salesforce.com, or should it use the partner community URL?

Comment: 1.Yes you cannot use that . 2) Fixed it .